# Is my Blood moon horde finished?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

Prior to v17.4 in 7 Days to Die, the Blood Moon Horde lasted from 22:00 to 4:00. After 4:00, horde zombies stopped spawning and existing zombies reverted to normal behavior.  In Alpha 17.4, I've started a new random gen single player game, and had my 7th day horde. At around 1:20am, no more zombies spawned. I know there's a limit to the number that can spawn at once, and I've seen them start wandering before, so I jumped down and ran around looking, and couldn't find a single one.  I did notice, however, that the color of the moon was no longer red. I've not seen this in any patch notes that I can recall, but does the color of the moon indicate when the blood moon horde is over?

As you can see in my screenshot, the sky seems the normal horde-night orange/red color, but the moon is grey.  Could this be the indicator?

[image]

Comment: It might be a bug - In the latest version of the game (Alpha 18.4) I've had blood moon hordes continue throughout the entire night.  But if I died, the horde seems to stop for a bit.  If I ran around some, zombies began to appear again.  I've also noticed that sometimes when 00:00 o clock rolls in, the red atmosphere goes back to normal, but then turns red again after a few moments.  Needless to say it's pretty strange behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to v18.4, once you got to the final wave of Horde night, zombies would trickle in up until the end of the horde night. **If you saw no zombies in a single player game after a certain point in v17.4, it was most likely because either**:

- They were spawned but stuck somewhere
- You encountered a bug

**As of v18.4, if you're using the default config,** [**there is a limit to the number of waves that appear during a horde night.**](https://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Blood_Moon_Horde#Simplified) After the last wave, no additional zombies will spawn. You can, however, override this via configuration edits.